# Setup NGINX server on VPS(ubuntu) behind NAT

Tags: php, linux, nginx, vps, nat

i own a small VPS (128mb vRAM) with a private IP 192.168.0.xxx a public IP xxx.xxx.xx.24 and 20 ports assigned to the private IP. The VPS is configured as a LNMP server. My config file for the website i want to run looks like this:
(it is in sites-available and linked to sites-enabled)

```
server {
    listen 12304 default_server; //12304 is one of the ports of my private IP
    listen [::]:12304 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root home/wordpress_acc/wordpress_website; // contains only a sample index.html
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name www.xyz.tk;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
    #error_page 404 /404.html;
}
```

When i try to acces the site via the domain www.xyz.tk or my public IP and the port 12304 (xxx.xxx.xx.24:12304) my webbrowser does not load the sample index.html but shows an error "could not connect to xxx.xxx.xx.24:12304 / www.xyz.tk

Is there somthing else i need to configure in NGINX or am i doing something wrong ?
Thank you for your time and efforts in advance!

PS: i am already running a TeamSpeak3 Server on this VPS which i have configured my self. It is running on one of the assigned ports and works just fine.

Edit: Just added a FTP server (vsftpd) on port 12305 and 12306-12310 and it is also working... but still not able to configure the NGINX server :-/

Comment: you might have some ports forwarded, but are they open on your vps?

Comment: i think so since my ts3 server is running on one of them